# EF Not Lazy Loading ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am trying to figure out why EF is lazy loading everything but my ApplicationUser property. I am using a generic repository pattern with the following domain object.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PickUpDate { get; set; }
    public PickUpTime PickUpTime { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentTransaction PaymentTransaction { get; set; }
    public virtual PromotionCode PromotionCode { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried doing the following

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

All the virtual properties except ApplicationUser get populated when I retrieve the entity from the database.

DBCONTEXT

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("name=DefaultContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(null);
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public IDbSet<PromotionCode> Promotions { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<PaymentTransaction> PaymentTransactions { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<BakeryOrder> BakeryOrders { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Child> Children { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BakeryOrder>().Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .ToTable("Users");
    }

    public static DatabaseContext Create()
    {
        return new DatabaseContext();
    }
}
```

REPOSITORY

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected DatabaseContext Context;

        public Repository(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Get()
        {
            return Context.Set<T>();
        }
}
```

SERVICE

```
public IEnumerable<Order> Get()
{
    return _orderRepository.Get();
}
```

Am I missing something here? This did work for some time and suddenly stopped, I have no idea why... the code base hasn't changed according to the commit logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity framework doesn't know what key to map it to because you don't have any property named "ApplicationUserId" so you must explicitly add the attribute pointing to the right foreign key.

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int PaymentTransactionId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PickUpDate { get; set; }
    public PickUpTime PickUpTime { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public decimal Discount { get; set; }
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public OrderStatus Status { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentTransaction PaymentTransaction { get; set; }
    public virtual PromotionCode PromotionCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I thought it worked from the property name, CustomerId and Customer? I'll give this a try.

Comment: indeed, Customer and CustomerId is enough, you don't need to specify the foreign key attribute.